# Extending Desktop Backgounds

Tags: desktop, customization

Apple already provide gorgeous photos for desktop background. How can i add photos to that collection? like "Desktop Pictures + My Folder"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `command + shift + g` in the Finder and enter "/Library/Desktop Pictures/" and click "Go". Add any pictures you want into this folder, and they'll appear in System Preferences as an option. You'll have to enter your password to add anything. You may have to restart System Preferences to see the changes though.